# Enumerating dynamic hits result using NEST 6.0 for Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, enumeration

The code below was working before `Nest 6.0` for enumerating dynamic hits result. But it throws `InvalidCastException` anymore.

**code:**

```
var response = elasticClient.Search<dynamic>(
                        s => s.Query(q => q.QueryString(m => m.Query(elasticQueryModel.QueryString))
                            ).Source(src => src.Includes(f => f.Fields(fields))).Size(querySize).AllTypes().Index(elasticQueryModel.Index));
var hits = response.Hits;
var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
foreach (var hit in hits)
{
     var source = (IDictionary<string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>)hit.Source;
     var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     foreach (var keyValuePair in source)
     {
            row[keyValuePair.Key] = keyValuePair.Value;
     }
     rows.Add(row);
 }
```

What is valid casting for hit.Source, or another solution for this code block?

Comment: What version of NEST are you using? And what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: Nest 6.0 and elasticsearch 6.0

Answer (score 5):

With NEST 6.x, the dependency on Json.NET is IL merged and internalized within the client. This has been done for a number of reasons, including:

- Removing the dependency on Json.NET and thus avoiding conflicts with regards to major versions when incorporating NEST into other projects already using Json.NET.
- Creating a clear boundary between serialization conventions applied to NEST types and any conventions that you may have for your own types
- Lays the foundations to look at alternative serialization libraries/techniques in the future e.g. async streams, `ArrayPool<T>`, `Span<T>`, etc.

This change means that using `dynamic` as the generic type on `Search<T>()` will no longer return source documents as Json.NET's `JObject`, but will be returned as instances of the internal type `Nest.Json.Linq.JObject`.

If you'd still like to use Json.NET in conjunction with NEST, then there is also the [NEST.JsonNetSerializer nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer) that allows you to [plug in your own serialization based on Json.NET.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/custom-serialization.html) *(The documentation is still in progress since NEST 6.x has not GA released quite yet)*.

The simpler scenario here though I think is to use `Dictionary<string, object>` as the generic parameter to `Search<T>()`

```
var response = client.Search<Dictionary<string, object>>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(m => m
            .Query("username")
        )
    )
    .AllTypes()
);

foreach (var hit in response.Hits)
{
    foreach (var keyValuePair in hit.Source)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: While `Dictionary<string, object>` works nice for simple cases, it would not work for fields with list of values. E.g. for document like `{"a": [1,2,3]}` you would get internal `JArray` as a value of `"a"` key in dictionary. And I was not able to find a way to read from it.

Comment: For more complex structures, you can still use `dynamic`, or plug in `JsonNetSerializer`, or define a POCO to deserialize into

Answer (score 1):

A working solution without casting could be as below. But, it works only for string key value pair.

```
var response = elasticClient.Search<dynamic>(
                        s => s.Query(q => q.QueryString(m => m.Query(elasticQueryModel.QueryString))
                            ).Source(src => src.Includes(f => f.Fields(fields))).Size(querySize).AllTypes().Index(elasticQueryModel.Index));
var hits = response.Hits;
var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
foreach (var hit in hits)
{
     var row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     foreach (var keyValuePair in hit.Source)
     {
            var pair = keyValuePair.ToString().Split(':');
            var key = pair[0].Replace("\"", "").Trim();
            var value = pair[1].Replace("\"", "").Trim();

            row[key] = value;
     }
     rows.Add(row);
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work for strings either. If your key or value have a colon character then the logic breaks